# Hide text if query has no posts

Tags: custom-post-types, query

I'm using a custom query to display events CPT inside another CPT. The given query has a section title, which I don't know how to hide when there are no events.

[image]

I've tryed to include the section title inside the This is the code:

```
<!-- EVENTOS -->
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <!-- Section title I want to hide when no posts found -->
        <div class="col-sm-12"><h2 class="seccion">Tour</h2></div>
        <?php
        $today = current_time('Ymd');

        $args = array(
            'post_type' => 'evento',
            'post_status' => 'publish',
            'numberposts' => '4',
            'meta_query' => array(
                'relation' => 'AND',
                array(
                    'key' => 'artista_del_evento', 
                    'value' => '"' . get_the_ID() . '"',
                    'compare' => 'LIKE'
                    ),
                array(
                    'key' => 'fecha_del_evento',
                    'compare' => '>=',
                    'value' => $today,
                    )
                ),
            'meta_key' => 'fecha_del_evento',
            'orderby' => 'meta_value',
            'order' => 'ASC',
            );

        $query = new WP_Query($args);
        if ($query->have_posts()) :
            while ($query->have_posts()) : $query->the_post(); 
        ?>

        <div class="col-sm-3">

            <?php 
            if(get_field('fecha_del_evento'))
            {
                $datetime = DateTime::createFromFormat('Ymd', get_field('fecha_del_evento'));
                $fecha_dia = $datetime->format('d');
                $fecha_mes = $datetime->format('M');
            }            
            ?>
            <div class="eventos row">
                <div class="col-xs-3">
                    <div class="fecha">
                        <p class="mes"><?php echo $fecha_mes; ?></p>
                        <p class="dia"><?php echo $fecha_dia; ?></p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-9">
                    <?php the_content (); ?>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>


    <?php endwhile; ?>
    <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>

<?php endif; ?>

</div><!-- #row -->
</div><!-- #container -->
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove line#5 and do the following:

```
if ($query->have_posts()) :
echo '<h2 class="seccion col-sm-12">Tour</h2>'; //we are showing the div inside the conditional
```

I removed unnecessary `<div>`, as `<h2>` itself is a block element and can do the trick for you.